# Can anyone help me how to interpret these numbers in USB HID?

Tags: usb, usb-hid

I am using a device in my optical setup.http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/dlpu010g/dlpu010g.pdf. I can project any images( 1, 2, .., 8 bit). I am not a programmer and it makes even more difficult to explain my problem. I need to tell when which color should be on the screen. To do so I need to modify the initialization parameter in setting configuration and send to the device (bit, time exposure,etc to fulfill my need.

There is a parameter that is written as: 0x00061800

I was wondering how to interpret these number and where they come from. I know this is a very general question and I might get warn from admins for this question but I appreciate if someone can give me hints or explanations at least how to understand this kind of commands.

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand what you are asking? I read the articles about your device. What is it meant to do overall, you plug it into ??? and it does ???

Comment: The device is used in an optical setup. I plug it into my computer so that I can project whatever image pattern onto the device and see it through the microscope. These pattern images have features like number of bit the exposure time, etc that can be modified through the configuration setting in a note file. There are some numbers that correspond to the data transfer in bit and byte which I cannot understand.

Comment: Where do I buy one and what is it used for? 1 byte = 8 bits, 2 bits = 1 HEX, RGB are 3 values that make a colour that range between 0-255, Yellow would be 255 of Red and 242 of Green and 0 of Blue. R is 8 bits long, G is 8 bits long B is 8 bits long. 24 bits makes a colour. I did see in your manual, one section is using 3 bits of data to represent 8 different settings an so on. But I still don't know what your doing or what it is?

Comment: on the website I shared you can see all the products and find the application. Basically it is used in video projectors. For example 0x00061800 This value corresponds to a sequence pattern from the tables I shared by images. These are USB commands sent to the device. My problem is I am not able to understand how the commands are written.

Comment: What page in the manual is that hex code

Comment: page 52 and 53.

Comment: There is a parameter that is written as: 00000000000001100001111100000000 is the code you have provided, my friend is about to come online an check this out, Hope you know I am trying, I enjoy problems. Wonder know one else has joined?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you explain me how to convert 0x00061800 into 00000000000001100001111100000000. I think this might be very helpful.

Comment: Yes I am trying to draw a picture for you now ok! It's easy

Comment: 00000000000001100001111100000000 is meant to be 00000000000001100001100000000000 I made a mistake, sorry :)

Comment: @Sarah Why did you delete the PDFs and related images? If your intention is to not have those items there this question should be closed because it makes no sense without them.

Comment: @JakeGould, I deleted them because it was not related to the PDF and images. The answer was independent from the information I provided, s it was hex into decimal and binary conversion. The PDF was the definition of the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Here is my drawing]

Ignore the 0x at the beginning, that is just saying to the computer you are getting a Base 16 number. Remember Base 16 goes from 0 - 15. The letter F represents 15, F converted to Base 2 would be 1111.